# Rsync only files matching pattern

Tags: rsync

It is inconceivable that this is proving to be so difficult but I'm trying to use `rsync` to copy only files matching a specific pattern. Specifically, copy files in all subdirectories matching `"*000.csv"`

You would think that the following

```
rsync -avrP --include='*000.csv' host:'~/data/' .
```

would do the trick. Instead this targets all files in all subdirectories (?!). [This blog](http://blog.mudflatsoftware.com/blog/2012/10/31/tricks-with-rsync-filter-rules/) suggests you can only "include" things that have been excluded first. Okay, so then why do these:

```
rsync -avrP --exclude='*' --include='*000.csv' host:'~/data/' .

rsync -avrP --filter='-! */' --include='*000.csv' host:'~/data/' .
```

both target no files at all. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: try `**/*000.csv` or `**000.csv`.   `*`  matches anything except slashes, `**` matches anything including slashes.  see `man rsync` and search for "PATTERN RULES".

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it looks like you are trying to copy from the remote host to your local machine. With that being said:

```
rsync -avP --include='*000.csv' --exclude='*.*' user@host:~/data ./
```

You don't need `r` as the `a` option implies `r`.

Comment: Thatll only get the files matching the pattern in the top level directory

Comment: Just tried it. It actually matches all files, even those that don't match `*000.csv` for some reason :(

Comment: The first command has been edited.